# Why C# compiler yield result for NULL and number comparison?

Tags: c#

I have the below code snippet which made TaskA to run when the Employee object is NULL (expected that to run TaskA only when the Employee ID not equals to 1).

```
if (Employee?.Id != 1) <PerformTaskA>;
```

Here, why C# compiler compares NULL and 1? shouldn't it throw exception? Also, what is the better practice to avoid these kind of cases?

Comment: That `.?` is called null conditional operator. It compares to `null`. If you want to avoid that, then just use `.`.

Comment: Even `if (1 == null)` is only a warning, not an error.

Comment: The condition in `if` is true when the `Employee` is null, or when the `Id` is not 1. When the `Employee` is null, it can have `Id=1`, therefore the condition is true.

Comment: a nullable `int` is certainly comparable to an `int` and if it's currently `null`, it's not equal to 1. *You wrote the code*, why do you expect it to compile but then throw an exception?

Comment: It sounds like you really want to perform task A "if there *is* an employee ID, but that ID isn't 1". That's not the same as "I'm not looking at an employee with an ID of 1", which is what the code you've got at the moment does.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If I would have defined nullable int and that fails with comparison with NULL then what you say make sense. But, how compiler can compare NULL with non-nullable int (i.e 1)? Also, the mentioned case made a defect in my development and I was wondering why exception was not thrown (and not like I intentionally write like it)

Comment: @paparazzo: "shouldn't it throw exception?" He is expecting an exception. And "why C# compiler compares NULL" he does not expect the compiler to check for null. All in all, he expects what `.` does and exactly the opposite of what `?.` does. That's my last comment on this.

Answer (score 2):

> Why C# compiler compares NULL and 1?

Because `Nullable<T>` is capable of comparing with `T` (or actually `int` becomes `int?` in this case). And in your case, it ends up with `null != 1` which is always true.

The easiest thing for you is to make this explicit:

```
if (Employee != null && Employee.Id != 1) <PerformTaskA>;
```

Comment: If I would have defined nullable int and that fails with comparison with NULL then what you say make sense. But, how compiler can compare NULL with non-nullable int?

Comment: Compiler magic or [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx) from `int` to `int?`?

Comment: The handling of `null` is somewhat special inside the compiler. If course, the implicit type conversion helps too. @ThomasWeller

Answer (score 1):

When you perform comparisons with `nullable` types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to `false` except for `!= (not equal)`. It is **important not** to assume that because a particular comparison returns false, the opposite case returns true. In the following example, 10 is not greater than, less than, nor equal to null. Only num1 != num2 evaluates to true.

```
int? num1 = 10;
int? num2 = null;
if (num1 >= num2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("num1 is greater than or equal to num2");
}
else
{
    // This clause is selected, but num1 is not less than num2.
    Console.WriteLine("num1 >= num2 returned false (but num1 < num2 also is false)");
}

if (num1 < num2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("num1 is less than num2");
}
else
{
    // The else clause is selected again, but num1 is not greater than
    // or equal to num2.
    Console.WriteLine("num1 < num2 returned false (but num1 >= num2 also is false)");
}

if (num1 != num2)
{
    // This comparison is true, num1 and num2 are not equal.
    Console.WriteLine("Finally, num1 != num2 returns true!");
}

// Change the value of num1, so that both num1 and num2 are null.
num1 = null;
if (num1 == num2)
{
    // The equality comparison returns true when both operands are null.
    Console.WriteLine("num1 == num2 returns true when the value of each is null");
}
```

> /* Output:
>
> - num1 >= num2 returned false (but num1 < num2 also is false)
> - num1 < num2 returned false (but num1 >= num2 also is false)
> - Finally, num1 != num2 returns true!
> - num1 == num2 returns true when the value of each is null
>
> */

Check this Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types).

Check the [Live Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bIdFpN).

Comment: Not exactly what is happening here.  null is compared to int 1.

Comment: @paparazzo - I have created fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/bIdFpN which demonstrate the null to int compare

Comment: OK you created a fiddle to compare int to null.   Still not what your answer does.

Answer (score 0):

`Employee?.Id` evaluates to `null` if Employee is null.
[?. and ?[] null-conditional Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Hover over this in Visual studio and you will get the answer

```
Debug.WriteLine(null != 1);
```

The expression will always be true because a value of type int will never equal null of type int?

It does not throw an exception.  Why did you not test this?

use

```
Debug.WriteLine(sc != null && sc.ID != 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You state "I have the below code snippet which made TaskA to run when the Employee object is NULL ".

For that, you'd want:

```
if (employee == null) {
    PerformTaskA();
}
```

(NB: I've put `employee` rather than `Employee` on the assumption that `employee` refers to an object rather than its class / to be in line with [naming standards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)).

Were you just comparing with 1 because ID 1 means the employee is not null?  That would also cause your task to run if the employee was not null but had any ID other than one; though I suspect you realised that?

Regarding comparison with a nullable type, see the documentation on [Nullable.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6(v=vs.110).aspx), which explains this behaviour.